# In MySQL how do I create a stored procedure that takes multiple parameters?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, call

Example of function:
**call getThings(amount, place, limit, marginError)**

SYNOPSIS: `CALL getThings(4, PA, 3, 1.2);`

example of goal:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getThings(IN amount X, place VARCHAR(30), lim INT, marginError double)
SELECT place, limit, amount
FROM AREA, PRODUCT
WHERE AREA.place=PRODUCT.place
AND PRODUCT.AREA=place
ORDER BY ABS(AMOUNT-marginError)
LIMIT lim;
END
```

Desired goal is to retrieve the closest 3 products from a stored procedure (using MySQL) but I keep getting sytax errors in trying to create the procedure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

since you didn't post the exact error/message,

> EDIT: I assume you are
>   missing the IN/OUT for the 2.and 3. parameter. - Not true, see comments.

e.g.

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE PROCEDURE getThings(IN amount X, IN place VARCHAR(30), IN lim INT)
   SELECT place, `limit`, amount
   FROM AREA, PRODUCT
   WHERE AREA.place=PRODUCT.place
   AND PRODUCT.AREA=place
   ORDER BY ABS(AMOUNT-5)
   LIMIT lim;
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: `IN`/`OUT`/`INOUT` specifiers are optional. By default parameters are `IN`

Answer (score 7):

`LIMIT` is MySQL's reserved word. If you really need to use it as column name, put in in backticks (``). Also, your paramteres have same names as columns in your table, which adds to confusion.

Comment: sorry that was a typo when cranking out the question (its been corrected)

Comment: No, it never was. I had lim in there

Comment: `SELECT place, limit, amount` <-- you sure there's no `limit` in here?

Comment: I am affraid you had LIMIT in your first version of your question, since i copied your code for the first version of my answer...